# How to fix a Laravel 8 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out sessions error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8, aws-aurora-serverless

**PHP:** 8.1.1
**Laravel:** 8.82
**Nova:** 3.31
**MySQL:** Serverless Aurora Mysql 5.7

4-days ago, randomly and seemingly not linked to any specific update we started receiving the following errors in Sentry. Around 7 per hour, a small amount of our traffic and intermittent. It's coming from various routes.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = XXXXXX9vd29o1pP3HMDRlxfGk4z1nhQfnRXXXXXX limit 1)

/nova/src/Http/Middleware/ServeNova.php in Laravel\Nova\Http\Middleware\ServeNova::handle at line 24
```

2-weeks ago we updated from Laravel 7 to 8.

As extra information and insight, if I run the following query directly on our MySQL server I get the following response:

```
select * from `sessions` where `id` = XXXXXX9vd29o1pP3HMDRlxfGk4z1nhQfnRXXXXXX limit 1

1054 - Unknown column 'XXXXXX9vd29o1pP3HMDRlxfGk4z1nhQfnRXXXXXX' in 'where clause'
```

This could be related, whether it's that Sentry displays the error this way or Laravel is missing the quotes around the ID and this is being reported as an 'Operation timed out' error. As a precaution I've changed the name of the session Cookie, hoping to clear any issues with strings. But this hasn't worked.

Any ideas or where to start debugging this would be appreciated.

Comment: tge text after the id = is a string and needs single quotes

Comment: @nbk I know, but that query is presumably being genorated by Laravel. Or it's how Sentry displays the error.

Comment: show the code or is it a secret

Comment: Happy to show more code. But wouldn't really know what to show, unless you have suggestions. This query is coming from Larvel core, with session cookies.

Comment: to reproduce we need a [mre] i think you have an error when passing the variqable, to the query builder, but to see that everybody need to see what you actqully do in that instance

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this. And I understand about the minimal reproducible example. But I don't know how to reproduce this myself, I'm looking for insight into where to start looking. I'm not creating that query, this code is all run in Laravel before it even starts executing the code that we have written, hence why I'm finding it difficult to provide code. I'm guessing it's an issue with old cookies on users' computers and the switch to Laravel 8 or something connection settings in AWS Aurora Mysql.